# Dispatching 'mouseover' event on links in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, dom-events

I have been experimenting with dispatching events in Firefox and noticed that dispatching the `mouseover` event on a link does not cause its style to change to that defined in the `:hover` CSS class. Dispatching the `click` event does change the link style to `:active`. Any reason for this behavior or I am doing something wrong in my code?

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("myLink");
var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
ev.initMouseEvent("mouseover", canBubble, cancelable, view, 
                     detail, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, 
                     ctrlKey, altKey, shiftKey, metaKey, 
                     button, relatedTarget);
myElement.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

If the event type is `click` it will execute the event and change **ev**'s style to one defined in `:active` pseudo-class.

I am trying to make a script which can record on-screen events and then play them back.

Update: Found [DejaClick](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3262) for Firefox. The hover on things like drop down menus does work properly.

Comment: please provide some code, it's hard to help you without more info

Answer (score 0):

Well from what i understand, you are using java-script to change the layout/display. Why not let CSS do all the work? If you can, simply use the :hover class. I assume however, you are trying to accomplish something non-style based. so... maybe you should look into jQuery's [hover event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover). Or possibly something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262740/javascript-onhover-event).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I am trying to change the layout/display using JS but at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery , and manipulate the link as you want, you can change the css, text, position, hide, add efects, and do what you want with it.

Example: if you want to manipulate all links in the same way

```
 $("a").hover(  
  function () { //this function is executed on every link
    $(this).css('color','red')); //add css atributes (see css documentation)
    $(this).animate( { width:"90%"}, 1000 )  //add efects (see efects documentation)
  },      
 );
```

you can also manipulate the link atributes, and do a lot of thing with it.
In the jQuery documentation you can find working examples of each, [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) ( see the jQuery API Reference ).

If you don't want to run the event on Hover on every link , you can bind it to the links that you want.
Examples:

```
//bind hover event to every link that match that id
$('#id_of_links').hover(function () { //manipulation } ); 
//bind hover event to every link that match that css class
$(".myClass").hover(function () { //manipulation } ); 
//bind hover event to every link by the text
$("a:contains('link_to_capture')").hover(function () { //manipulation } );
```

And there are a lot of ways to select the link you want to manipulate, see the Selectors section in jQuery docs.