# Hover highlight multiple div tags

Tags: javascript, css, html, mouseover

Attached is an image showing what I'm looking for. As the mouse hovers over boxes all the boxes above the mouse are highlighted. Boxes are totally separate

I cannot for the LIFE of me figure this out!

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262740/javascript-onhover-event. Then in your hover handler you can change the class of the div so it's lit up.

Comment: possibly you are calling the colour change function/code on mouseenter & forgot to revert back on mouseleave

Comment: the totally separated blocks are siblings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't say anything about your markup, I built something from scratch using jQuery:

**JavaScript**

```
$('.container > div').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).prevAll().addClass('active');
    },
    function() {
        $('.container > div').removeClass('active');
    }
);​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.container > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
}

div.container > div:hover, div.container > div.active {
    background: red;
    color:white;
}
```

​
**DEMO**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/wFN9t/)

Comment: This worked out GREAT for me - thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

A pure CSS means is possible, given the following HTML mark-up:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <!-- other elements -->
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>
​
```

with the following CSS:

```
div {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 1em auto;
    min-height: 2em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

div.box { /* default */
    background-color: #009;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container:hover .box {
    background-color: red;
}

.container:hover .box:hover ~ .box {
    background-color: #009;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QFUES/).

This does, of course, require a browser that supports the general-sibling `~` combinator and, again 'of course' that the elements are siblings.

Unfortunately, with margins between the `.box` elements, this [does cause flickering](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QFUES/1/) (when the `:hover` moves off the `.box` elements to the parent `.container` element)

References:

- [CSS general-sibling `~` combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

Comment: +1 This one is pretty sleek, if IE 8 is not important. :)

Comment: Thanks! ...I must admit I wasn't quite sure if it'd *work* when first I tested it! =D ...though I'm a little disappointed at the [flickering in the event of margins](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QFUES/1/); which I can't think of a way around, unfortunately.

Comment: @DavidThomas http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QFUES/3/ why not do just contianer be same as box in width ?

Comment: @eicto: no reason at all, but anyway the margins to *centre* aren't a problem in, and of, themselves; it's just the margins that vertically separate the elements that are problematic. And if the posted image is accurate then that *shouldn't* be a problem; the only reason I mentioned the flickering problem is to forewarn, really.

Answer (score 0):

This **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6LKWg/)** should do it:

```
$('div').mouseover(function() {
    var x = $(this, 'div').index();
    $('div:lt(' + (x + 1) + ')').addClass('red');
    $('div:gt(' + x + ')').removeClass('red');
});​
```