# a:hover CSS style affecting browser-based behaviour of buttons containing image

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I asked this question earlier from my phone but it became very convoluted and confusing so I decided to start over after finding a usable PC. Note that I can't give the full original code nor images due to the project's classified nature which is also located offline. The bare-bones version below contains the same problem anyway, so I'm quite certain being able to solve the problem in this example code will be adequate for me to troubleshoot anything else in the actual application.

I have the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/mssdjrzk/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    button {
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
      padding: 4px 0 0;
    }
    img {
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <button type="button">
      <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/famfamfam_mini_icons/action_refresh_blue.gif">
    </button>
    <hr>
    <a>Sample link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the cursor hovers over the button, a default browser-based behaviour is triggered. In the case of IE 11, the button is highlighted.

Next, I add additional CSS for `a:hover`: https://jsfiddle.net/yLrznyss/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    button {
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
      padding: 4px 0 0;
    }
    img {
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <button type="button">
      <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/famfamfam_mini_icons/action_refresh_blue.gif">
    </button>
    <hr>
    <a>Sample link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, when I hover my cursor over the button, the behaviour is messed up - the behaviour does not render, although other events like `onclick` renders normally. I have done a lot of troubleshooting and attempts to workaround without success, but here are my findings:

- The offending element is `:hover`. It doesn't matter what element/class/id is attached to it, its very existence in the stylesheet is enough. Even `a:hover {}` which contains no styling will cause the problem too, as does `span:hover {}` when no `<span>` elements even exist in the HTML.
- I tried it on Chrome, but the problem does not exist since Chrome's default hover behaviour for buttons is rendered differently. **This is thus a browser-specific problem.**
- The problem only exists for buttons containing images, as opposed to buttons containing text, empty buttons or standalone images not inside anything.

My guess is that the existence of the `:hover` CSS in the stylesheet, even if it's empty, is causing issues in how IE renders the resultant web page and its behaviour.

**How can I prevent the button and/or its internal image from being affected, thus returning to the default IE button hover behaviour?** I can change anything, as long as the desired hover style on the hyperlinks is achieved without affecting the buttons.

The full application which uses this code will use IE11 on Windows 10 - not any other browser. **Solutions using HTML, CSS or JavaScript are acceptable but no external libraries** are available to my project.

Comment: I can't see any highlights on the button for either jsfiddle. I can see the `<a>` highlighting on the second one though.

Comment: hmm? I can see it though? My project PC uses Windows 10, this PC I'm typing on is Windows 7 Pro. Both uses IE 11. I can see it on my browser. Have you tried copying the source code into Notepad and opening it on IE?

Comment: Hmm, can't really help you then, since I'm on a MAC and can't access Internet Explorer.

Comment: There was some problems with button hover (with button borders, if I can recall correctly) in IEs, I can't reproduce your issue with Win10 + IE11, though. Have you checked that you don't have any nested (LESS/SASS?) style rules in your stylesheet?

Comment: I don't think so? I created a blank Notepad file and then typed the above code in, that's all. So I think whatever is affecting the webpage should all be there...right?

Comment: As said, I can't reproduce, I see turqoise (or something near that) hover color on the button in both fiddles (IE version 11.187.14393.0).

Comment: I tried it on both IE 11.0xx and IE 11.2xx. If you put `border: 1px solid black;` on `img`, you can see the area occupied by it. I hovered my cursor over the button outside of the image, and the button highlights, but when my cursor moves inside the bounds of the image, the highlight is gone.

Comment: @Teemu I investigated my problem further and narrowed down the issue I'm facing. Heavily edited the above to trim off irrelevant parts. Hopefully you can at least provide some useful insights, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've no idea, since I can't reproduce the issue. The hover effect in your fiddles seems to work as expected also when emulating IE10 or IE9 (with IE11). The button issue I referred in a previous comment, was about IE showing active borders after clicking, despite of setting border to none. Also it seems, that this issue is also fixed in later updates. Maybe you've an issue with the GPU of your machine, or GPU-settings in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see any anchor links inside the button. I used this code:

```
  button:hover {
      background: red;
    }
```

And was able to get the hover effect you are looking for

Comment: Exactly, there aren't any `<a>` inside `<button>` at all but somehow this problem is happening. Your solution is a workaround I've considered, but do you know what the button's on-hover colour code is? I need to use the same colour.

Comment: That's not the original, default colour of the button when I hover over it. I need that one.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a successful workaround. Since I can't use the `:hover` selector, I have to mimic it via JavaScript. Credits to [Javascript onHover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262740/javascript-onhover-event) for the solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <style>
    button {
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
      padding: 4px 0 0;
    }

    img {
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
    }

    .isHovered {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var links = document.getElementsByTagName("A");

      for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
        (function() {
          var link = links[i];
          var hoverTimer;

          link.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            hoverTimer = setTimeout(function() {
              link.className = "isHovered";
            }, 0);
          });

          link.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
            link.className = "";
          });
        }());
      }
    });
  </script>

  <body>
    <button type="button">
      <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/famfamfam_mini_icons/action_refresh_blue.gif">
    </button>

    <hr>

    <a>Sample link</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would welcome any better answer though, or at least an explanation of why I have this problem - if you are able to replicate it on your machine.