# how to find event of the Default tooltip of any element

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

My question is very simple. Below is simple code, in which I have only one span with title. I want to know where can i find the event default tooltip is shows.

```html
<span title="some stubborn tooltip">text</span>
```

Note: Its not about Jquery or CSS, I am talking about pure JavaScript here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is not existing events... You can make you own, by start a timer when mouse in hover an element during 1s : tooltip is showed

Comment: @Alexis Can you please elaborate more? I don't want any own tooltip. I just want to debug at the point when default tooltip is showed. It may sound silly or unimportant, but I just want to know it.

Comment: What do you want to debug?

Comment: "I want to know where can i find the event default tooltip is shows." Do you mean to sense the hover event??

Comment: @GermanLatorre ... I want to debug whatever event is called when you hover on the element and tooltip shows. Is it possible or not according to you?

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary yes, could not found it yet.

Comment: @Maharshi why not "onmouseover" event?? That would do right??

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary agree with you. Can you please show some code which can help?

Comment: I want to know everything like which is the element of the tooltip, how it calculates the position (that may be simple because of the mouse cursor position) etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<span title="some stubborn tooltip" id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">text</span>
<script>
function mouseOver() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
}

function mouseOut() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "black";
}
</script>
```

Does this help? It's a simple mouseover and mouseout event.

**EDIT** You can mimic a custom mouseover and mouseevent [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262740/javascript-onhover-event)

**EDIT2 as per your comments** The implementation for title as a hover text is shipped along with the browser. It depends on the which browser you are using. Some browsers neglect it, some consider only `alt` attribute, in some you have to use both `alt` and `title` together for the tooltip to work.

The fancy tooltips that we see are basically `div`s and `span`s and other html elements styled accordingly to serve our requirements where in the hover elements are placed on top of other elements using css features like `z-index`, `postion` etc. The code for implementation of the tooltip which we get by adding `title` attribute is shipped with the browser.

Comment: Thanks for an attention, but I know it. what I want to know is, how javascript appends little tooltip box (yellow background and black border) on the page.

Comment: I didn't get the "yellow background and black border" part.. are you talking about a textbox background when it is clicked?

Comment: I am talking about tooltip box in which "some stubborn tooltip" text is written. it appears when your mouse enters over the span.

Comment: @Maharshi Definitely that code is written somewhere, it is coded and shipped as an browser feature..  I updated my answer

Comment: So basically, the answer is we can not dig into the browser's default events to modify it. And we can not see what JavaScript do to show us the tooltip ???

Comment: No, you can't.  Why should you want to do such a thing? :-)

Comment: @Maharshi yes we can't dig into the browser's code implementation and modify it :-) . If you want to modify it, you got to go with the other fancy plugins as I've explained. Do mark the answer if you think it helped :-)