# Cancel hover action when no longer hovering?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a situation where when a user hovers a button, it should display a little popup after a slight delay.

```
tt = angular.element(element);
  ...
  showTooltipFn = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      tt.tooltip("show");
    }, 700);
  };
```

However, when you say hover the mouse quickly over the other buttons, it will display all the buttons you hovered. I only want to display the popup on the button that it is currently hovering. If I am no longer hovering cancel the show.

Is there a way to do this with AngularJS? Check if I'm still hovering something?

Comment: This is not Angular-specific, but you may gain some inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262740/javascript-onhover-event#263194).

Comment: ngMouseLeave? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave

Comment: @infamoustrey Awesome that seems to have worked thanks. I think I tried that before but must have done it wrong or something the first time.

Comment: @Carson No problem!

Comment: Or just use simple CSS. `:hover` to trigger the visibility, and with a transition to only show it after 700ms.

Comment: I highly recommend the [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tooltip) directives. Specifically for this situation `uib-tooltip` has a `tooltip-popup-delay` setting that would achieve what you want without having to write code in your controller to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ngMouseLeave](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave) lets you evaluate expressions upon mouseleave.

Example from AngularJS Docs

```
<button ng-mouseleave="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
  Increment (when mouse leaves)
</button>
count: {{count}}
```

For your case...

```
        var timeoutPromise;
        showTooltipFn = function() {
          timeoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
            tt.tooltip("show");
          }, commonOptions.delay.show);
          tt.on("mouseleave", function() {
            $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
          });
        };
      }
```