# Have a div filled with elements appear when hovering a link, code not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll

I seem to have trouble with what should be a simple thing.
I can't figure out why what I did isn't working, I want to have an element appear when a link is hovered, but nothing happens when it's done. It only works when I ask the element to appear when the container is hovered, but not for the link.

```css
.elementcontainer {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cardtitle a:hover + .elementcontainer {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="maxthumb">

  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="elementcontainer">
      <p class="element">text1</p>
      <p class="element">text2</p>
    </div>

    <h2 class="cardtitle">
      <a class="text-white" href="http://...">Title</a>
    </h2>

    <p class="cardsub">text2</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

I basically have to have the element appear when the link is hover with a simple animation like a fade in or a slide in but so far I can't even have them appear on hover.

Comment: `+` is immediate sibling selector. Meading that your `div` should immediately follow your link to work

Comment: They are not siblings so you can't use a sibling selector. In addition the `+` does not look up the dom tree

Comment: Will require JavaScript.

Comment: yes, css3 doesn't work that way ... you can't point to the previous dom element at all, no such a selector and `+` does the next (first) sibling, `~` does any next sibling

Answer (score 0):

They are not siblings so you can't use a sibling selector

But try this javascript code : onmouseenter ,onmouseleave event

```js
function show(){document.getElementsByClassName('elementcontainer')[0].style.opacity="1";}
function hide(){document.getElementsByClassName('elementcontainer')[0].style.opacity="0";}
```

```css
    .elementcontainer { opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="maxthumb">
   <div class="card-body">
      <div class="elementcontainer">
          <p class="element">text1</p>
          <p class="element">text2</p>
      </div>
      <h2 class="cardtitle">
         <a onmouseenter="show()" onmouseleave="hide()" class="text-white" href="http://...">Title</a>
      </h2>
      <p class="cardsub">text2</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: How could I adapt this to a slide in/fade animation rather than simply a hide/show ? I got no knowledge of js

Comment: than use css property transition in  .elementcontainer class    ` .elementcontainer{ transition:0.5; }`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works with elements above the hovering object but if you put the link above it should work. I guess you can still rearrange the layout in css if you want the link below.

```
<div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="cardtitle">
            <a class="text-white" href="http://...">Title</a>
        </h2>

        <div class="elementcontainer">
          <p class="element">text1</p>
          <p class="element">text2</p>
        </div>
        <p class="cardsub">text2</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not using the same css rule it won't. The `<a>` has no siblings for a sibling selector to work on. See [answer]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a sibling that follows an element change when that element is hovered, but you can't affect a previous sibling in the same way. I refactored your code a bit to make it work

```css
.card-body {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cardtitle:hover + .card-body {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="maxthumb">

    <h2 class="cardtitle">
      <a class="text-white" href="http://...">Title</a>
    </h2>

  <div class="card-body">
      <p class="element">text1</p>
      <p class="element">text2</p>
    </div>

    <p class="cardsub">text2</p>

  </div>
```

Comment: It works if I then use position : absolute to visually rearrange the div to put it above despite it coming after in the code. Not a big fan of this solution in this particular case since it is something that repeats often and not a one time occurence on a page

Answer (score -1):

You can attach an event to the hover with JavaScript to change CSS attributes. As shown in the other answer above.
JQuery : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp
JavaScript mouseover: [Javascript onHover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262740/javascript-onhover-event)

Comment: SASS nesting is something completely different than what Op is trying to do

Comment: Exactly I was pointing out he couldn't do it that way with ]CSS and then provided a solution?

Comment: Fine but the `.elementcontainer` is not a descendant of the `<a>` so how would this rule help?

Comment: He edited his question, I made changes to reflect your comments which are correct in this case. Thanks